# flutter get stuck at resolving dependencies for android

Tags: flutter

I am using Android Studio for flutter

My flutter doctor says no issue found, when I run iOS app, it works but when app is requested to run as Android app, android studio just hangs up on Resolving dependencies.. what issue can be there?  is it downloading something or any other issue?

Comment: A quick tip which can help is to use 
File -> Invalidate Caches/Restart

Comment: did you fixed this problem? @Shahbaz Ali

Comment: if you are running flutter to Android App for very first time, it takes sometime, so please be patient and wait.. request is to have better speed internet.. becuase it downloads some graddle files. as soon as it completes, app will run.

Answer (score 14):

If that's the first Flutter app that you are running I suggest you to give it some time. I am using i5 QC 3.2GHz / 16ram machine and it took me about 10 minutes the first time. At first it get stuck at:

> Initializing gradle...

and then again at

> Resolving dependencies...

after the first launch, it's running reasonably fast.

Answer (score 10):

Open project root directory in terminal and enter command:

```
android/gradlew
```

This will install dependencies related with gradle build system.

Answer (score 2):

Open the project root directory in the terminal and run

```
flutter clean
```

and then run the project

Comment: question was asked almost 2years before. please remove your negative marking.. it reduces my points, please..

Comment: Do you have a stable internet connection?

Comment: Also make sure your Anti-Virus does not interrupts the downloading process

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer to your question is "yes, it is downloading some dependencies". It may take a while depending on your internet connection. I know this was asked a while ago but I encountered the same problem recently.
P.S. Don't forget to accept android licenses if you haven't already done so.

Answer (score 1):

./flutter_project_name/android/gradlew

After successful build.
Try run the project again.

Answer (score 0):

Note : install java and add jdk../bin  to environment variables

```
1.go to this folder ::  "your_project_folder/android/"
2. delete ".gradle"
3. open cmd in that directory 
4. type "gradlew" in cmd
```

after this run app normally : " flutter run "

Answer (score 0):

Update your flutter plug-in

- Settings
- Package and plugins
- Update or installed -> update
- Restart ide

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It needs to download all important android dependencies for your app to run. If you are stuck there then kindly check your internet connection and wait for a while. Mine below, took almost 20mins before all dependencies were resolved. [image: Android dependencies]

Answer (score 0):

It's downloading your dependencies for the first time.
it'll take time if you're doing for the first time.
just let it complete now ,from next time it'll not take this much time.

Answer (score -2):

I fixed it by making a new flutter project and adding a random dependency. When I went back to the old project it worked fine.